# How are 10-20 digit multiperfect and hemiperfect numbers efficiently computed?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics, perfect-numbers

This [numericana item on multiperfect and hemiperfect numbers](http://www.numericana.com/answer/numbers.htm#multiperfect) contains some impressively enormous numbers.  **How were these actually computed ?**  The associated OEIS pages ([A007691](http://oeis.org/A007691) & [A159907](http://oeis.org/A159907)) just give brute force code which (at least briefly playing with PARI) isn't going to scale up beyond $10^{10}$ or so on sane timescales.  This suggests there's some ways of doing it more efficiently (any links or tips?)... or is this what supercomputers are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the sum of divisors function is multiplicative.  We have that $\sigma(p^n)=\frac {p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$ for $p$ prime and $\sigma(rs)=\sigma(r)\sigma(s)$ for $r$ coprime to $s$.  So you look for combinations of prime powers that cancel off the denominators.  You need lots of prime factors, which therefore need to be pretty small, so you can ignore a lot of numbers.

Comment: Indeed.  Having now solved a Project Euler problem involving such numbers, it's quite surprising how small the contributing factors remain.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers can be found in Ron Sorli's thesis at http://hdl.handle.net/2100/275.